# Debian terminal - how can navigate from history list?

Tags: linux, debian, terminal, command-history

I want to use <kbd>Ctrl + r</kbd> to navigate in commands history, but I want to see all list of commands.

I want to view the list of `history | grep some-term` commands and going "up" or "down" choose the proper command I want to use.

I saw someone who add this somehow to his Mac terminal (maybe z-shell) and wondered if there is something similar to Debian Linux.

Comment: you can just use history command & call back !12 or !number of a command, use ctrl+R use alt+R or alt-O to run found command  you may have all of this depending on you shell.

Answer (score 0):

If your unhappy with the default <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> behaviour, I recommend you to install [`fzf` (fuzzy finder)](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf).

Fzf replaces the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> search with a *so-much-better* one. It has a lot more features for finding files and much more.

You should read the README from the the [github page](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) and the [Examples from the wiki](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/wiki/examples).

**Installation:**

```
git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.git ~/.fzf
~/.fzf/install
```